# how to run zeppelin 0.8.0 interpreter on different host?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have two hosts, one with zeppelin and another where I want to run *jdbc interpreter*, problem is that in *0.7* I could run it like this:

```
<br> /opt/zeppelin/bin/interpreter.sh -d /opt/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc -p xxxx<br>
```

but from 0.8 they add new parameters **CALLBACK_HOST** and **INTP_PORT** and I script throws errors:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer.main(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:266).

Please advise how to start this interpreter with zeppelin *0.8.0* and what exactly this parameters mean because there is almost nothing on github.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can find `callback_host` in the configuration such functionality is not available now.

The JDBC interpreter could run only on the same host as Zeppelin server.